# Couldn't load type 'KingAOP.AspectWeaver'

Tags: c#, dynamic, aop

I'm struggling with this for a quite time and frankly I have no idea what might be the cause.

After the free-fun with PostScript I was interested in testing its fully free and open-source alternative called KingAOP.

Basing on mini-tutorial from here (https://github.com/AntyaDev/KingAOP) I've created simple console application. After compiling and running the aplication, I'm getting this error:

```
"Could not load type 'KingAOP.AspectWeaver' from assembly 'KingAOP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.":"KingAOP.AspectWeaver"
```

It's thrown when `HelloWorldCall()` is being invoked.

Sources:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
        helloWorld.HelloWorldCall();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

```
class HelloWorldAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnEntry: Hello KingAOP");
    }
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnExit: Hello KingAOP");
    }
}
```

```
class HelloWorld : System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
{
    [HelloWorldAspect]
    public void HelloWorldCall()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
    public System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression parameter)
    {
        return new AspectWeaver(parameter, this);
    }
}
```

Because KingAOP is not avaible in nuget repository, I donwloaded github project, builded and add it as DLL library to my project.

Comment: Could you please send me your project...? (or publish it on github or bitbucket) It's strange error... For more information, please follow http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/624586/Introducing-the-KingAOP-Framework-Part
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/633095/Introducing-the-KingAOP-Framework-Part-Exception

Comment: I'm not sure if I still have this project on my disk. I don't remember if I've resolved this issue too. I'll try to reproduce this case in free time and let you know.
Thanks for help!